# @RolesAllowed and web-tier in Java EE 6.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

I have a web application with a set of security constraints. Web app calls `ejb` modules annotated with `@RolesAllowed` and everything's fine - once authorized, user's credentials being passed to `ejb` and security constraints are applied accordingly.

But hell, I just don't understand why should I wrap each and every call from web modules to `ejb` in a `try-catch` block or create exception handlers, looking for `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException` as a root cause and generate 403 server response code by hand in case user's credentials don't meet security constraints for a specific `ejb` method.

Isn't it something that could be delegated to the Java EE web container? Do I miss something here?

Comment: Can't you just define generic error handlers in a filter and/or web.xml?

Comment: @home, yes I can and I do unwrap exceptions recursively looking for their root cause, but why? What's the reason behind leaving it as my responsibility and not making it as a default behavior for a java ee app?

Comment: what you think the default should look like? And already today you do not have to 'wrap each and every call from web modules', you can just define a handler 'above'...